# Fastest way to get month, day, year, from date string

Tags: php, mysql, database, string, date

I am getting a date from the mysql database:

here is what it comes out as:

```
2017-01-20
```

what would be the fastest way to get the month, day, and year, so for example, when i echo, it will be like this:

```
echo $month; //01
echo $day; //20
echo $year; //2017
```

Comment: Hints: `month('2017-01-20'), year('2017-01-20'), day('2017-01-20')` in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have that string in a variable called `$date`

```
$date = '2017-01-20';
```

You can [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it into a [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) if you are sure the format is consistent:

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $date, 3);
```

You could convert the date to a time integer using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to use in other functions like [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). This has the added benefit of being able to test that this is a well-formed date:

```
$time = strtotime($date);
if ($time === false) die("Bad date format: $date.");
$year = date('Y', $time);
$month = date('m', $time); // 'n' if you don't want leading zero
$day = date('d', $time);   // 'j' if you don't want leading zero
```

As [jasonmoqio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7127712/jasonmoqio) points out, since you asked for fastest, [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is a tiny bit faster than exploding. (On my workstation looping substr vs. explode 10 million times only produced an improvement of 1/1000th of a second over exploding, so unless this is in a loop that gets run millions of times, you will not notice the difference and should opt for code readability.)

```
$year = substr($date, 0, 4);
$month = substr($date, 5, 2);
$day = substr($date, 8, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you know that the output will consistently be a string in the format "YYYY-MM-DD", the most basic approach is:

```
<?php

    $query = ... //query is your string "YYYY-MM-DD"
    $year = substr($query, 0, 4);
    $month = substr($query, 5, 2);
    $day = substr($query, 8, 2);

    echo $month;
    echo $day;
    echo $year;
?>
```

Comment: The third argument to substr is length, not position. so the first should be `$year = substr($date, 0, 4);` and so on.

Comment: My apologies for the language mess up. My answer has been edited.Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to bug again, but the month and day need a length of 2, the length is not 0-based.

Comment: Thank you! I mistook length=0 as retrieving the char, not length=1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$date = new DateTime('2017-01-20');
echo 'Year:'.$date->format("Y");
echo 'Month:'.$date->format("m");
echo 'Day:'.$date->format("d");
```

Output:

```
Year:  2017
Month: 01
Day:   20
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to quickly get the date from mysql, try using regex like this.

```
if (preg_match('/^(?P<year>\d+)[-\/](?P<month>\d+)[-\/](?P<day>\d+)$/', $your_date, $matches)) {
    $mydate = $matches['year'] . "-" . $matches['month'] . "-" . $matches['day'];
    $whatever = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tgl));
    // You can echo it...
    // echo $matches['year'];
    // echo $matches['month'];
    // echo $matches['day'];
}
```

Hope this help you out. :D