# How can I separate a single column into 3 separate columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Want to execute a query to view single date-month-year time column to separate date column, month column and year column.

eg

```
 joining_date
 01-JAN-22 12.00.00AM
```

to

```
joining_date|joining_month|joining_year
          01       |     JAN      |    22
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to get month, day, year, from date string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263688/fastest-way-to-get-month-day-year-from-date-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some ways of doing this:

If your data is always in this `01-JAN-22 12.00.00AM` format , no matter what comes after 22, you can use substring.

```
select substring('01-JAN-22 12.00.00AM',1,2) as joining_date,
       substring('01-JAN-22 12.00.00AM',4,3) as joining_month,
       substring('01-JAN-22 12.00.00AM',8,2) as joining_year;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> joining_date  joining_month   joining_year
>       01           JAN              22
> ```

Another option is converting the string to proper date datatype an use MySQL functions, like :

```
select DAY(str_to_date('01-JAN-22 12.00.00AM', "%d-%b-%y")) as joining_date,
       MONTH(str_to_date('01-JAN-22 12.00.00AM', "%d-%b-%y")) as joining_month,
       YEAR(str_to_date('01-JAN-22 12.00.00AM', "%d-%b-%y")) as joining_year ;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> joining_date  joining_month   joining_year
>       1            1             2022
> ```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c1576b331c3b4648e7015dcbe39bc1a2)

Comment: this query will execute only the date which are 01-JAN-22 and what if i want all the joining date of the joining date column to be shown in separate columns, in such case what should be the query.

Comment: @user19541968 change `'01-JAN-22 12.00.00AM'` with the column name . Check this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c101abaac1f0422f0b01f91df830a49

Answer (score 0):

Use YEAR, MONTH and DAY syntax:

```
SELECT  
YEAR(`joining_date`) as joiningYear, 
MONTH(`joining_date`) as joiningMonth, 
DAY(`joining_date`) as joiningDay
FROM tableName
```

If you want your month name, then use `MONTHNAME`:

```
SELECT  
YEAR(`joining_date`) as joiningYear, 
MONTHNAME(`joining_date`) as joiningMonth, 
DAY(`joining_date`) as joiningDay
FROM tableName
```

Comment: This will produce wrong(null to be specific) results because MySQL date functions work on proper date data type , not a string one

Comment: @ErgestBasha, is that a non datetime type of column the user is referring to?

Comment: No, it is a string one. MySQL proper date format is YYYY-MM-DD , check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html#:~:text=MySQL%20retrieves%20and%20displays%20DATE,%3Amm%3Ass%20'%20format.